# How to use js/css to make tab content viewable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on tab

There are 5 tabs

About Us
Our Work
**Our Team**
News & Events
**Contact us**

and inside each of them there are content and links, images.

What i am trying to achieve here whenever i click the link inside the tab ***Our Team content***,

It should open the **Contact us Tab content**.

Here is the code i am using currently, It has some custom js and jquery 2.2.0 used.

Please check the code, i haven't put css here.

The live link of this example is [Live Demo](http://university.nepromedia.com/christopher-kolade-centre-for-research-in-leadership-and-ethics/#)

Please help me

```js
// TABS
    var tabs = $('.container_tabs');
    $('.tabs-content > div', tabs).each(function (i) {
        if (i != 0) $(this).hide(0);
    });
    tabs.on('click', '.tabs a', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var tabId = $(this).attr('href');


        $('.tabs a', tabs).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('.tabs-content > div', tabs).hide(0);
        $(tabId).show();

    });

    // var tabs1 = $('.container_tabs1');
    // $('.tabs-content > div', tabs1).each(function (i) {
    //     if (i != 0) $(this).hide(0);
    // });
    // tabs1.on('click', '.tabs a', function (e) {
    //
    //     e.preventDefault();
    //
    //     var tabId = $(this).attr('href');
    //
    //
    //     $('.tabs a', tabs1).removeClass();
    //     $(this).addClass('active');
    //
    //     $('.tabs-content > div', tabs1).hide(0);
    //     $(tabId).show();
    //
    // });

    (function ($) {
        jQuery.fn.lightTabs = function (options) {

            var createTabs = function () {
                tabs = this;
                i = 0;

                showPage = function (tabs, i) {
                    $(tabs).children("div").children("div").hide();
                    $(tabs).children("div").children("div").eq(i).show();
                    $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").removeClass("active");
                    $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").eq(i).addClass("active");
                };

                showPage(tabs, 0);

                $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").each(function (index, element) {
                    $(element).attr("data-page", i);
                    i++;
                });

                $(tabs).children("ul").children("li").click(function () {
                    showPage($(this).parent().parent(), parseInt($(this).attr("data-page")));
                });
            };
            return this.each(createTabs);
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs cw-wrapper">
            <ul class="cw-30">
               
               <li class="" data-page="0">About Us</li>
               
               <li data-page="1">Our Work</li>
               
               <li data-page="2">Our Team</li>
               
               <li data-page="3">Our Partners</li>
                              
               <li data-page="4" class="active">Work With Us</li>
                              
               <li data-page="5">Contact us</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="cw-70">
               <div class="content" style="display: none;">   
                  Content 1
               </div>
               <div class="content" style="display: none;">
                  Content 2 
               </div>
               <div class="content" style="display: none;">
                  Content 3
               </div>
               <div class="content" style="display: none;">
                  Content 4
               </div>
               <div class="content" style="display: none;">
                  <h3>Contact us Content</h3>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: so, basically, you just want to use jquerry to open one div, and hide all the others, if I understood your question correctly?

Comment: A *quick* look at your `tabs.on('click',` doesn't show any problems - not sure why you need all that convoluted code `lighttabs` code which looks very brittle.

Comment: Can you describe the *exact* problem you're having and why you think your code doesn't work?  So far you've just said "I'm trying A and here's my code".

Comment: @freedomn-m Check the below answer, the answer is nearly there but i want it without inline click javascript. Please guide me

Comment: @Hadi290 has done the hard part of *understanding* what you're asking, so it would be rude for me to provide another answer on top of that effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to switch tabs by links that are inside your tab contents too. In that case you should create a function for switching tabs, instead of a click event in you menu. here is an example:

**edit #1:**
I removed all onclicks and bind switchTab function to all elements that have switch-tab class.

**edit #2:**
As requested, you can pass initial tab number from url `?tab=x` [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hadi290/pen/jpBvYZ?tab=2)

```js
// set tab from url
// sample url: http://mywebsite.com/my-route?tab=2
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = new URL(window.location.href);
  var tabNumber = url.searchParams.get('tab');
  if (tabNumber)
    switchTab(tabNumber);
});

// change tab by clicking an element with "switch-tab" class
$('.switch-tab').on('click', function(e) {
  var tabNumber = e.target.getAttribute('data-tab');
  switchTab(tabNumber);
});

// change tab by passing tab number 
function switchTab(tabNumber) {
  $('#tabs li').removeClass('active');
  $('#tabs li[data-tab=' + tabNumber + ']').addClass('active');
  
  $('.content').css('display', 'none');
  $('.content[data-content=' + tabNumber + ']').css('display', 'block');
}
```

```html
<style>
  #tabs li.active {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .content {
    display: none;
  }
  .content.visible {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs cw-wrapper">
  <ul class="cw-30" id="tabs">
    <li data-tab="0" class="switch-tab">About Us</li>
    <li data-tab="1" class="switch-tab">Our Work</li>
    <li data-tab="2" class="switch-tab">Our Team</li>
    <li data-tab="3" class="switch-tab">Our Partners</li>
    <li data-tab="4" class="switch-tab active">Work With Us</li>
    <li data-tab="5" class="switch-tab">Contact us</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cw-70">
    <div class="content" data-content="1">   
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-content="2">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-content="3">
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content visible" data-content="4">
      <p>Content 4</p>
      <a href="#" data-tab="5" class="switch-tab">go to contact us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-content="5">
      <h3>Contact us Content</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please remove inline js from list and make it work that way?

Comment: `$("[data-content a").click(function() { switchTab($(this).closest("[data-content]").data("content")); })` and `$("ul.tabs>li").click(function() { switchTab($(this).data("tab")) });`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks it would be great if you will share your edit with his code.
Yes He did a great work, i just want to make it work with external js without any inline js. Please help me.

Comment: @Hadi290 Thank you so much, for tab content you used different style, can you please make it work on my code above. For example, on my code tab content div contains style="display: none;" , can you please make it work there?
or it will work there auto?

Comment: @NimeshDeo add my two css `.content { display: none; }` and `.content.visible { display: block; }` to your css file and remove the inline `style="display: none;"` from your html. It should work fine.

Comment: @Hadi290 Inline css is generated by js i think, is there any other way? I think your idea will work as well after applying !important, right?

Comment: @NimeshDeo Yes. Inline style override all other css. by adding !important to both css it should work. or you can change .content style in switchTab function instead on add/remove .visible class.

Comment: @Hadi290 Can you please make the final changes as you said?, It's good to go.
Thanks for your Answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176562/discussion-between-hadi290-and-nimesh-deo).